# How to use sed and find to replace text based on list

Tags: awk

I have two files I would like to work on
I need to replace text in file 1 with text in file 2

file one

```
client:datavalue
client:datavalue
client:datavalue
```

file two

```
datavalue:newdatavalue
datavalue:newdatavalue
datavalue:newdatavalue
```

I would like to create a script which if data value in file 1 and 2 are the same it replaces them with newvalue from file 2

datavalue and newdatavalue are never the same

The solution given by Francesco Lucianò

Return me this

```
join: file1:2: is not sorted: client:datavalue
join: file2:477715: is not sorted: datavalue:newdatavalue
```

I try with LOCALE=C same result

UPDATE i fixed the return with adding --nocheck-order

but i still stop in process

Sometimes i don't have newdatavalue in file2 for value in file1 maybe i think it's because of that

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think `find` is the command you need... Maybe it's `join`. Check the `man find` page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to be sure `find` is what you're looking for.

Comment: [edit] your question to fix your sample input to show representative values of each field rather than the same string for every occurrence of each field and show the expected output given your updated sample input. Also include your attempt to solve the problem yourself. See [ask].

Comment: This is definitely not a job for `sed` or `find` btw. `join` or `awk` might be appropriate.

Comment: It's okay for you a script?

Comment: Not every routine/function/method/operator/keyword has a tag. Please choose tags from a list & read their wikis. Tag [tag:join] is for the relational DB operator.

Answer (score 0):

if you run those commands in the sequence I wrote them you will get the result you want. You can also save them in a script and run it, if you know how to do it. Here the commands:

```
sort -k2 -t: file1 > file1.sorted;
sort -k1 -t: file2 > file2.sorted;
join -1 2 -2 1 -t: -a1 file1.sorted file2.sorted -o '1.1 2.2 1.2' | sed -E 's/::/:/g;s/([^:]+):([^:]+):?[^:]*/\1:\2/g' > file1;
rm file1.sorted file2.sorted;
```